# how to shoot continuously while pressing spacebar in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Don_tgetthatcincp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void shoot() //shoot funtion
        {
            bullet.Left += 50;
            if (bullet.Left > 50)
            {
                bullet.Image = Properties.Resources.bullet;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            while (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                shoot();
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            shoot();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a simple shooting game using windows form in c# but the problem is, my game only shoot once when i run it. everytime i hit the spacebar it doesn't produce bullet. Can you help me out? thankyou. here's mycode.

Comment: The name of that namespace `Don_tgetthatcincp` looks unnecessarily complicated, can you explain it please?

Comment: I think that you need to scrap what you have and rethink the logic. This time actually think the logic all the way through first, then write code to implement that logic. The first question is whether you want a single bullet on screen at a time or multiple.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `shoot` in the `Tick` event handler but you never `Start` the `Timer`, so that `Tick` event is never raised.

You should be starting the `Timer` on `KeyDown` and stopping it on `KeyUp`. I also just realised that you had a `while` loop rather than an `if` statement, which doesn't make sense:

```cs
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        shoot();
        timer1.Start();
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shoot();
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

EDIT:

Further to that, the `shoot` method doesn't actually do what I expected it would. It doesn't actually shoot but rather just moves the bullet tot he right. At no point in that code do you create another bullet or reset the existing bullet to the left. It seems to me that this is the sort of code you end up with when you write it without actually knowing what it's supposed to do. If you only want one bullet at a time then you need to rest its `Left` back to zero when it hits something or leaves the screen. If you want multiple bullets then you need to some way to handle that. There's no one way some I can't just tell you how to do it.

Comment: _"...you never Start the Timer"_ - Timers can be set to _enabled_ via the designer.  Also this doesn't explain the problem in the non-timer scenario:  **Spacebar** and why it works only once.  I suspect the OP has a _deeper_ issue.

Comment: @MickyD, that's true, but if that were the case then the `shoot` method would be being called without the spacebar being pressed at all. That said, looking at the code more closely, there does seem to be more wrong here than just the `Timer` not being started. I think I'll add to my answer.

Comment: That's right.  There's quite a few fundamental issues with the OP's code.  I suspect the OP wants to animate the bullet as well as have an autofire, hence the timer and the possibly-misnamed `shoot()` method which probably should be `Animate()`. It needs alot of work. I started to write an answer but I lost interest.  +1 regardless :)